# Problem in writing a JUnit test case for the Spring method

Tags: java, spring, junit

I test the following method by JUnit, but I am stuck up in mapping the attributes

```
@RequestMapping("/a/{b}/c/{d}")
public @ResponseBody String getTranslatedXliff(Model model, 
   @PathVariable String templateCode, @PathVariable String localeCode){

    // ...
}
```

Comment: You'll need to explain better what you're trying to do and what's not working.

Comment: Instead of asking the same question again, update this one with your new explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Just call it:

```
@Test
public void test_whatever() {
    controller.getTranslatedXliff(myModel, "my template code", "my locale code");
}
```

There's nothing magic about annotated method parameters.